# C++ char* as a function parameter

Tags: c++

How can I pass a char pointer (`char*`) to the function `func()`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(char *var)
{
    cout << var;
}

int main()
{
    char* test = "Hello World";
    func(test);
}
```

The compiler says:

> Initialization: const char[12] cannot be converted to char *

Comment: `char* test = "Hello World";` is illegal in `c++` so you should have had an error on that line. It has to be `const char* test = "Hello World";` since c++11 which was the 2011 standard.

Comment: side note, this is valid c code (Not the cout bit, but the char* manipulation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *string literal* is a `const char[N]` array in read-only memory (where `N` is the number of characters in the literal, plus 1 for the null terminator, so in your case `11+1=12`).  You can't point a `char*` pointer (ie, a pointer to non-`const` data) at a string literal, as that would allow for the possibility of altering read-only data, which is *undefined behavior*.

Simply change your pointer type to `const char*` instead (ie a pointer to `const` data), eg.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(const char *var)
{
    cout << var;
}

int main()
{
    const char* test = "Hello World";
    func(test);
}
```

Otherwise, as you say you have no control over the function declaration, then if you really want to pass a string literal to a `char*` pointer, you should copy the characters into a separate writable `char[]` buffer first, and then point at that instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(char *var)
{
    cout << var;
}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "Hello World";
    func(test);
}
```

Or, if you **know** for sure that the function will *never* modify the characters, you *can* just cast off the `const`-ness using `const_cast` (though this is **highly NOT recommended**, I'm including it for completeness), eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(char *var)
{
    cout << var;
}

int main()
{
    char* test = const_cast<char*>("Hello World");
    func(test);

    /* alternatively:
    const char* test = "Hello World";
    func(const_cast<char*>(test));
    */
}
```

Comment: For your second example I get the following error:

`Syntax error: unexpected token "]", expected "id expression"`

Comment: I think you meant: `char test[] = "Hello World";`

Comment: That was already corrected before you posted your comments. Maybe you hadn't refreshed the page yet.

Comment: @RobinFauser If you have control over the function in question, i'd personally go with his first suggestion.

Comment: I have no control over the function because it is actually a DLL call.

Comment: @RobinFauser Then chances are, the DLL was not written for C++, but for C, where pointing non-const `char*` pointers to string literals is legal and common (but not any less dangerous!). In that case, using an intermediate `char[]` is best, but if you *know* the function will not modify the data then you can simply cast off the `const`, such as with `const_cast`. I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code is now working!

Answer (score -5):

This code would print the string "Hello World"

```
void func(char *var) 
{
    for( ;*var!='\0'; var++) {  //!= from null terminator  
        cout<<*var;
    }
}
int main()
{
    char test[] = "Hello World";
    func(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of printing one character at a time in a `for` loop instead of simply doing `std::cout << var;` ?

Comment: Because this would only print the first element of the string 'H'.
Edit: Actually you are correct, but in my answer i refered to the pointer '*var' in the cout statement. In my case the for loop was needed.

Comment: @dennis `for( ;*var!='\0'; var++) { cout<<*var; }` is identical to `cout<<var;` no loop needed. `operator<<` is overloaded to handle a null-terminated `char*` pointer. So, the only *useful* thing provided in your answer is `char test[]` and you didn't even focus on that.

Comment: @dennis The loop is also potentially slower since it'll have to construct and check the sentry object once for each character instead of once for the whole string.